# Return something else if type is None or NoneType

Tags: python

I have this method that retrieves a value from a SQL query:

```
def get_base_price(self, date):
    sql = """
    SELECT TimeSeriesValue
    FROM dbo.TimeSeriesPosition
    WHERE  
    TimeSeriesTypeID = {0} AND
    FundID = {1} AND
    SecurityMasterID = 45889 AND
    EffectiveDate = '{2}'""".format(self.LAST_PRICE_ID, self.FUND_ID, date)

    with self.job.rap.connect() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            price = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()[0] 
            if price is NoneType:
               return 100
            else:
                return price # Returns base price value
```

I have a test, but i'm not able to return 100 if `price` is `None`. My running test just returns `NoneType` object is not subscriptable'

I've also tried: `100 if price is None else price`, that didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: `if price is None`

Comment: Your error `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'` is not coming from your return statement, it's coming from the previous line: `price = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()[0]` implying that the `fetchone()` function is returning `None` and then you're attempting to subscript it with `[0]`

Comment: The error message tells you that you can't use subscription on the *type* of the instance that you tried to access. So `None[...]` results in `'NoneType' is not subscriptable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are subscribing on `None` *before* that test:

```
price = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()[0]
```

`.fetchone()` returned `None`, and it is `None[0]` that triggers the exception:

```
>>> None[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The error message tells you that the type of `None`, which is `NoneType`, doesn't implement subscription support. If you look closely at the traceback Python prints out, you'll see it's the `price = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()[0]` line where the exception is thrown and the code will never get to the `if price is ...` line that follows.

Call `.fetchone()` without subscribing, then test for `None`:

```
with self.job.rap.connect() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        price_row = cursor.fetchone()
        if price_row is None:
            return 100
        else:
            return price_row[0]
```

Alternatively, you could use a tuple assignment *and* use exception handling to return a default instead:

```
with self.job.rap.connect() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        try:
            price, = cursor.fetchone()
            return price
        except TypeError:
            return 100
```

You should also *not use string formatting* to combine data with a query. Use SQL parameters:

```
sql = """
SELECT TimeSeriesValue
FROM dbo.TimeSeriesPosition
WHERE  
TimeSeriesTypeID = %s AND
FundID = %s AND
SecurityMasterID = %s AND
EffectiveDate = %s"""

with self.job.rap.connect() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql, (self.LAST_PRICE_ID, self.FUND_ID, date))
        try:
            price, = cursor.fetchone()
            return price
        except TypeError:
            return 100
```

Each `%s` in the query is a placeholder, and the values for those placeholders are passed into the `cursor.execute()` call as the second parameter. The *database driver* then takes responsibility for properly quoting the values for each column, ensure that there the data can't be executed as a SQL command instead; note that there are no quotes around the `%s` placeholder for the `EffectiveDate` column. This lets you avoid a SQL injection attack and makes it possible for the database driver to re-use the query plan for the given query, which is more efficient for the database.

Comment: THAT WAS IT. Thank you!! Would you suggest using the tuple? I'm kind of new to Python not sure what's the best convention in this case.

Comment: @user7496931: pick whatever feels more comfortable to you. The `price, = ...` assignment will also throw a `TypeError` if there is more than one column in the result row, which would let you detect an error in your code sooner.

Comment: @user7496931: on the other hand, the `,` in that assignment is subtle and can cause confusion for developers inexperienced with Python's tuple assignments.

Comment: @user7496931: more important is the SQL parameter advice, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access index `0` of `price` before checking if it is `None`, thus trying to access `None[0]`.

```
price = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()[0]
#      this may very well be None ---^
```

You should fetch, check that `price` is not `None` and only then subscribe to it.

```
price = cursor.execute(sql).fetchone()
return price[0] if price is not None else 100
```

As a sidenote, you shoud check that `price` is `None`, and not `NoneType` which is its type. To use `NoneType`, you would need to check `if isinstance(price, NoneType)`, but this not how objects are checked against `None`.

Comment: @user7496931 can you add the full traceback to your question?

Answer (score -1):

```
return 100 if price is None else price
```

This simple `if` will check the value for `None` and return the desired result.  I originally did this with `if price`, but that doesn't work when the price is 0 -- 0 is also `falsey`.

Comment: You should also fix the explanation; besides, the problem turned out to be the line above.